# SF DX: create data when creating a package

Tags: salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

While creating package version, I have a process that is causing the package build to fail because it references a message template record that is missing in the scratch org that is being built as part of the packaging process.  Is it possible to add data to a scratch org prior to creating the package version?

UPDATE

I'm trying to include one of these Messaging Templates in my package:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, the org that is "created" as part of the version creation process is not a Scratch Org (that's a term reserved for an org you create via force:org:create). Second, your package must be a fully-formed package, or have all of its dependencies satisfied by other packages. You cannot insert data during the creation process. You will need to either include the missing metadata, or update your unit tests or code such that they won't fail when the data is missing. You can choose to skip validation (`--skipvalidation`) in order to quickly iterate and test in a Scratch Org, but this will prevent certain types of installations, as a package that skips validation cannot be "promoted" to the "released" status.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the terminology for me.  It is the package version creation that is failing, not any unit tests.  I'm lost at how to include a process in an unlocked package that is dependent on a particular record being present.  In my case, its an Email Template.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak You can package an Email Template as well. In fact, if your metadata depends on it, it should be in the package version.

Comment: I can't see how to add a Messaging Template to an unmanaged package, or select it.  In the unmanaged package UI, it isn't listed under Email Templates.  See above screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak Try `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m MessagingTemplate`

Comment: I tried that and "MessagingTemplates".  Both returned:  No results found